# core-image missiing after building yocto for a beaglebone black board

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto, beagleboneblack

Good morning,

I have tried to build a yocto image for a beaglebone black by following the template on this website: **[https://android.serverbox.ch/?p=1273](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FogcA.png)**

After nearly a day of construction, I have checked my build folder (**yocto/poky/build/tmp/deploy/images/beaglebone**) to find all the necessary file

- ML-beaglebone
- U-boot-beaglbone.img
- uImage

But I can't find "**core-image-base-beaglebone.tar.bz2**   (The root file system)

Anyone knows what happend? Did i do something wrong? What else can I do to resolve the problem?

Here is the script I typed in the shell to launch the build:

- **bitbake core-image-base**

I have attached a picture of the folder as well. So you can see the file that are in my folder.

thank you in advance for your help

Michael

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FogcA.png)

Answer (score 0):

Add the below line in the `local.conf`.

`IMAGE_FSTYPES += "tar.bz2"`

Launch the build

```sh
$ bitbake core-image-base
```

After the build core-image-base-beaglebone.tar.bz2 will be created in `yocto/poky/build/tmp/deploy/images/beaglebone`